# 2D quantum harmonic oscillator eigenvalue solution in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: differential-equations

My question is concerning eigenvalue solution of the Schrodinger equation with harmonic potential in 2 dimensions which is defined as follows,

[image]

where U(X,Y)= (x^2+y^2)/2, I have solved the 1d SE using sinc approximation, so I try to solve the 2d with same approach, to ease my calculations, I use the transformed 2d SE from cartesian coordinates into polar as following:
[image]

then i solve for the r independent variable equation above assuming homogenous phi. Then I transform the equation using simple mathematics into [image]

where i solve the following kummer equation using sinc method approximation:
[image]

The eigenvalue solution should be E = (2n+1)hw for n=0,1,....
The output solution is not correct as desired because the error of the solution is between 10^-2 to 10^-1 which is not acceptable.
I solve the polar SE using the following code

```
       sSincr[r_] := Sinc[\[Pi] r]
        sincSSr[r_, k_, h_] := sSincr[(r - k h)/h]
    Options[\[Phi]] = {AlgebraicDecay -> False};
    \[Phi][r_, a_, b_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
     Block[{algebraicDecay}, algebraicDecay = OptionValue[AlgebraicDecay];
       Piecewise[{{Log[(r - a)/(b - r)], -\[Infinity] < a && 
          b < \[Infinity]}, {If[algebraicDecay, Log[r - a], 
          Log[Sinh[r - a]]], (0 == a && b == \[Infinity]) || (a > 0 && 
            a < \[Infinity] && b == \[Infinity])}, {If[algebraicDecay, 
          Log[Sqrt[r^2 + 1] + r], r], -\[Infinity] == a && 
          b == \[Infinity]}}]]
    Options[\[Psi]] = {AlgebraicDecay -> False};
    \[Psi][r_, a_, b_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
     Block[{algebraicDecay}, algebraicDecay = OptionValue[AlgebraicDecay];
       Piecewise[{{(a + b E^r)/(
         E^r + 1), -\[Infinity] < a && b < \[Infinity]}, {If[
          algebraicDecay, a + E^r, 
          Log[Sqrt[E^(2 r) + 1] + E^r + a]], (0 == a && 
            b == \[Infinity]) || (a > 0 && a < \[Infinity] && 
            b == \[Infinity])}, {If[algebraicDecay, Sinh[r], 
          r], -\[Infinity] == a && b == \[Infinity]}}]]
M = 0;
precission = 300;
kummereq2 = 
  2 (-t F''[t] - ((M + 1) - t) F'[t] + 
      1/2 (M + 1) F[t]) == \[Mu] F[t];
Nt = 100;
rDerivative = {Derivative[1][S][k_] :> 
    Piecewise[{{0, k == 0}, {(-1)^k/k, k != 0}}], 
   Derivative[2][S][k_] :> 
    Piecewise[{{-\[Pi]^2/3, k == 0}, {-2 (-1)^k/k^2, k != 0}}]};
aptSolution = Sum[U[k] S[(\[Phi]1[t] - k h)/h], {k, -Nt, Nt}];
tequation0 = 
  kummereq2/. F -> Apply[Function, {t, aptSolution}] // Expand;
(* --- symbolic discretization --- *)
tequation1 = 
  tequation0 /. {t -> \[Psi]1[m h]} /. \[Phi]1[\[Psi]1[xx_]] :> xx;
tequation2 = Table[tequation1, {m, -Nt, Nt}];
(* --- replacement of derivatives --- *)
tequation3 = SetPrecision[tequation2, precission] /. rDerivative;
tequation4 = tequation3 /. S[n_] :> KroneckerDelta[n, 0];
(* --- replacement of conformal maps with the specific definition --- \
*)
a = \[Infinity];
tequation5 = 
  tequation4 /. 
     h -> SetPrecision[N[(23 \[Pi])/(25 Sqrt[Nt])], 
       precission] /. \[Psi]1 -> 
     Function @@ {xx, \[Psi][xx, 0, a]} /. \[Phi]1 -> 
    Function @@ {xx, \[Phi][xx, 0, a]};
tequation6 = tequation5 /. {\[Mu] -> 0};
tequation7 = SetPrecision[N[tequation6], precission];
tA = Last[
    Normal[CoefficientArrays[tequation7, 
      Table[SetPrecision[N[U[k]], precission], {k, -Nt, Nt}]]]] // 
   Simplify;
tA // MatrixForm ;
teigenSys = Chop[Eigensystem[tA]];
{tvals, tvecs} = {Reverse[First[teigenSys]], Reverse[Last[teigenSys]]};
tvals
```

The output eigenvalue solution from tvals is not acceptable when compared with the theoretical solution {1,3,5,...}
Please help

Comment: Did you seen this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200448/eigenvalue-problem ?

Comment: You made substitution  $t=\lambda r^2$ and then in your code  there is `tequation6 = tequation5 /. {\[Lambda] -> 0};`. How we can understand this substitution? Note, that in the equation (42.7) $\lambda ^2=1/2$

Comment: the lamda used in the book (flugge for quantum mechanics ) is not the eigenvalue calculated , it is just a factor of transformation, while in my code the lamda is the eigenvlaue solution

Comment: Ok! But how we know that $\lambda$ in the book and $\lambda$ in the code not same parameter? Can you highlight this difference ore just rename $\lambda$ in the code?

Comment: I changed the eigenvalue for my problem to be mu in the code

Comment: Thank you! It looks like your code has an error of $h^2$, so you don't need option `precission = 300`. For this code we can put `precission = $MachinePrecision` .

Answer (score 1):

We can check first, that code above not reproduces eigenvalues in 1D for equation `eq1d=-u''[t]/2+t^2/2 u[t]` by replacing `kummereq2` with `eq1d`. It should be `{0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5, ...` while we got `{1.500000000230585, 3.500000000661840, 5.499999999874578, 7.499999991862981, 9.49999995724386, 11.49999984296917, 13.49999952929730, 15.49999882009192, ...`. Thus there is an error in sinc method implementation. To clear this point we take our code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200448/eigenvalue-problem) for 1D oscillator

```
exactdelta = h1^2 D[S1[\[Phi]1[x], j, h1], {\[Phi]1[x], 2}];

ex = exactdelta /. x -> \[Psi]1[x] /. \[Phi]1[\[Psi]1[x_]] :> x /. 
   x -> k h1;

ex1 = ex /. S1 -> Function[{x, k, h}, Sinc[\[Pi] (x - k h)/h]];

Nn = 137;
h = \[Pi]/Sqrt[2 Nn];
h1 = h; nabla2 = 
 ParallelTable[
  If[k != j, N[ex1], -(\[Pi]^2/3)], {k, -Nn, Nn}, {j, -Nn, Nn}];
vx[x_] = -x^2/2 /. x -> k h;

vx1 = Table[vx[x], {k, -Nn, Nn}];

vxmat = DiagonalMatrix[vx1];


A = -nabla2/2 - vxmat;
eigs = Eigensystem[A];
lambd = Reverse[Select[Abs[First[eigs]]/h, # < 30 &]]
Show[ListPlot[{Table[1/2 + i, {i, 0, 29}], Abs[lambd]}, 
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> {"Exact", "Numeric"}, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"Nn = ", Nn}]], Plot[x - 1/2, {x, 0, 30}]]
```

We have `Out` of this code as expected

```
`{0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5, ...`
```

Now we turn it to 2D case with `M=0` as follows

```
exactdelta = h1^2 D[S1[\[Phi]1[x], j, h1], {\[Phi]1[x], 2}];

ex = exactdelta /. x -> \[Psi]1[x] /. \[Phi]1[\[Psi]1[x_]] :> x /. 
   x -> k h1;

ex1 = ex /. S1 -> Function[{x, k, h}, Sinc[\[Pi] (x - k h)/h]];

Nn = 137;
h = \[Pi]/Sqrt[2 Nn];
h1 = h; nabla2 = 
 ParallelTable[
  If[k != j, N[ex1], -(\[Pi]^2/3)], {k, -Nn, Nn}, {j, -Nn, Nn}];
vx[x_] = -x^2/2 /. x -> k h;

vx1 = Table[vx[x], {k, -Nn, Nn}];

vxmat = DiagonalMatrix[vx1];


A = -nabla2 - vxmat;
eigs = Eigensystem[A];
lambd = Reverse[Select[Abs[First[eigs]]/h Sqrt[2], # < 60 &]]
Show[ListPlot[{Table[1 + 2 i, {i, 0, 29}], Abs[lambd]}, 
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> {"Exact", "Numeric"}, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"Nn = ", Nn}]], Plot[2 x - 1, {x, 0, 30}]]
```

Finally we have output of this code as expected

```
{1., 3., 5., 7., 9., 11., 13., 15., 17., 19., 21., 23., 25., 27., 29., 31., 33., 35., 37., 39., 41., 43., 45., 47., 49., 51.0001, 52.9997, 55.0009, 56.9972, 59.0066}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: thank you so much for your help, it really cleared the problem

Comment: there is a problem, that if you try to solve the kummer equation using the same procedure, it will fail because the equation is changed from the one you solved over 1D

Comment: @mohamed-ayman It is not clear what do you try to compute. From one side you try to solve 2D harmonic oscillator with `sinc` method and the answer is above.  From the other side, you try to solve Kummer's equation with `sinc`.  But how you know that sinc is appropriate method to solve Kummer's equation?

Comment: the kummer equation is the 2d harmonic oscillator equation after removing the theta equation from the polar harmonic oscillator equation as seen above in the last image in the post.