# Finding excited states using the condition of wave functions orthogonality

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, numerics, mathematical-optimization, eigenvalues

This is the continuation on my previous question [Why does the minimum eigenvalue change dramatically when one basis function is added to the basis set?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284809/why-does-the-minimum-eigenvalue-change-dramatically-when-one-basis-function-is-a#284841)

Brief description of the problem: I would like to find excited states of this system: $$H=-\frac{1}{2}\Delta-\frac{1}{r}+\frac{25}{8}\rho^2-5/2$$where $r=(\rho,z,\phi)$ is a coordinate in the cylindrical system. The basis functions have the following form: $\psi_j=e^{-b_{j} z^2}e^{-a_{j} \rho^2}$, where $a_{j}$ and $b_{j}$ are parameters.

The energy of the ground state $(E_{min}=-1.3803982710899914)$ was found by @Alex Trounev using variational approach and this value is in excellent agreement with data from the literature (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284809/why-does-the-minimum-eigenvalue-change-dramatically-when-one-basis-function-is-a)). The energies of excited states for this system are also known from the literature: $E_{1}=-0.193746$ (the first excited state), $E_{2}=-0.07365$ (the second excited state), $E_{3}=-0.03835$ (the third excited state), etc.

To find the excited states, @Alex Trounev suggested using a penalty method described here https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.13556.pdf .

Let's start by finding the first excited state ($|\Psi_1\rangle$):

Following the article, the first excited state can be found as follows: $|\Psi_1\rangle=\operatorname{argmin} (O[\Psi_1])$ (formula 1 in the article), where $O[\Psi_1]$ is the objective functional. The objective functional has the following form: $O[\Psi_1]=E[\Psi_1]+\lambda_0|\vec{S}_0-\vec{S}_0^*|^2$ (formula 7 in the article), where $S_0=\frac{\langle\Psi_1|\Psi_0\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle\Psi_1|\Psi_1\rangle\langle\Psi_0|\Psi_0\rangle}}$ (formula 8 in the article), and $\vec{S}_0^ * $ is a set of target overlaps (If I understand correctly, in our case it is equal to 0).

Table 1 of the article shows the scheme of actions for finding excited states. In order to get the values from this scheme, let's turn to section II B of the article.

First of all, let's write the ground state function $|\Psi_0\rangle$, which is the anchor function in this problem. It was found in the [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284809/why-does-the-minimum-eigenvalue-change-dramatically-when-one-basis-function-is-a).

In the code I renamed $\rho\equiv r$ for convenience.

The ground state:

```
In[154]:= ClearAll["Global`*"]
al = {1.25, 1.25003, 1.25006, 1.251393, 1.252726, 1.2587955, 1.264865, 1.260499, 1.303186, 1.546232, 2.337185, 4.507307, 9.426298, 20.270036, 43.977048, 95.675215, 208.32642, 453.736619, 988.32236, 2152.803005, 4689.357171, 10214.647096};
bl = {0.026284, 0.0417685, 0.057253, 0.090983, 0.124713, 0.1981855, 0.271658, 0.417292, 0.61588, 1.008925, 1.949878, 4.24735, 9.251849, 20.15297, 43.898488, 95.622497, 208.291042, 453.712878`, 988.306428, 2152.792314, 4689.349997, 10214.642282};
cl = {0.006523295622643919`, -0.06054266302240082`, 0.14648250087347384`, -0.3150221502945908`, 0.416620632871218`, -0.3601131808535824`, 0.3912230593543366`, 
   0.012038542224830733`, 0.16818770546793724`, 0.17778604904585182`, 0.1738326674769321`, 0.12492347058872014`, 0.08226422142736733`, 0.05675211101544814`, 0.03735559092913218`, 0.026154779461694356`, 0.016669555882257724`, 0.01271934679906752`, 0.006364816098521608`,
    0.00797395974846925`, -0.0001602541764108519`, 0.006595023995239419`};
nmax = Length[al];
(*the basis function*)
a[j_] := al[[j]];
b[j_] := bl[[j]];
Psi[r_, z_, j_] := Exp[-b[j]*z^2]*Exp[-a[j]*r^2];
(*the ground state function*)
c[j_] := cl[[j]];
Psi0[r_, z_] = Sum[c[j]*Psi[r, z, j], {j, 1, nmax}]
```

Formula 9 from the article:

```
(*the 1st excited state*)
(*the basis function*)
Psi1[r_, z_, j_] := Exp[-b1[j]*z^2]*Exp[-a1[j]*r^2];
(*ρ0=|Psi0(|^2)+|Psi1(|^2)(formula 9 in the article)*)
Psi02[r_, z_] := 
  Sum[c[l1] *c[l2]*Psi[r, z, l1]*Psi[r, z, l2] , {l1, nmax}, {l2, 
    nmax}];
Psi12[r_, z_] := 
  Sum[c1[l1] *c1[l2]*Psi1[r, z, l1]*Psi1[r, z, l2] , {l1, nmax}, {l2, 
    nmax}];
ρ0[r_, z_] := Psi02[r, z] + Psi12[r, z]
```

Relative normalization (formula 11 and 10 in the article):

```
N0 = NIntegrate[
  Psi02[r, z]/ρ0[r, z]*r*2 Pi, {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

There are 66 parameters (`a1[j]`, `b1[j]` and `c1[j]`) in the problem (with the current choice of the excited state function structure). In order to find the derivative with respect to each parameter for relative normalization, the authors give formula 12:

```
Psi11[r_, z_] := Sum[c1[l] *Psi1[r, z, l] , {l, nmax}];
da1N0 = 2*
   Re[NIntegrate[(
      E^(-r^2 a1[1] - z^2 b1[1]) *(-r^2)*c1[1]*Psi11[r, z])/ρ0[r,
        z]*r*2 Pi, {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]];
db1N0 = 2*
   Re[NIntegrate[(
      E^(-r^2 a1[1] - z^2 b1[1]) *(-z^2)*c1[1]*Psi11[r, z])/ρ0[r,
        z]*r*2 Pi, {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]];
dc1N0 = 2*
   Re[NIntegrate[(
      E^(-r^2 a1[1] - z^2 b1[1]) *(-r^2)*Psi11[r, z])/ρ0[r, z]*
      r*2 Pi, {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]];
```

A few questions:

1. I took a certain set of numbers as parameters of the excited wave function (`Psi11`) and checked the calculations of the normalization factor and its derivatives, Mathematica gives errors. Is it due to the fact that I misunderstand the formulas from the article?
2. The scheme shown in Table 1 (in the article) is not very clear, especially points (c)–(i). If you could write these points more simply, it would help me a lot.

I would be glad to any comments on solving the problem. 
I am sorry for the not quite typical question, but in the context of my previous questions, which make up the topic series, finding a solution to this problem is of interest.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, your comments are needed )

Comment: *Mathematica gives errors.* What are they?

Comment: @Ghoster, errors of this type *evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{3.,1.},{0.,352422.}}*. I just tried to check these formulas with certain given parameters, the correct values of which should be found later from minimization (penalty method).

Comment: "In the code I renamed rho to r. "  The Hamiltonian in the first line is defined with rho the plane radius, while 1/r is the spherical Coulomb potential. Your problem is not existent, neither in mathematics nor in physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute exited states we can use the penalty method as follows. Note that any exited state wave function is orthogonal to the ground state, therefore  $\langle\Psi_1|\Psi_0\rangle=0$. We use this equation as constraint for minimization problem. First we compute ground state

```
a0j = {1.25, 1.25003, 1.25006, 1.251393, 1.252726, 1.2587955, 
   1.264865, 1.260499, 1.303186, 1.546232, 2.337185, 4.507307, 
   9.426298, 20.270036, 43.977048, 95.675215, 208.32642, 453.736619, 
   988.32236, 2152.803005, 4689.357171, 10214.647096};

b0j = {0.026284, 0.0417685, 0.057253, 0.09098300000000001, 0.124713, 
   0.19818550000000001, 0.271658, 0.417292, 0.61588, 1.008925, 
   1.949878, 4.24735, 9.251849, 20.15297, 43.898488, 95.622497, 
   208.291042, 453.712878`, 988.306428, 2152.792314, 4689.349997, 
   10214.642282};
nmax = Length[a0j]; var = 
 Join[Table[a[n], {n, nmax}], Table[b[n], {n, nmax}], 
  Table[c[n], {n, nmax}]];
Psi[r_, z_, j_] := Exp[-b[j]*z^2]*Exp[-a[j]*r^2];



(*kinetic energy*)
Kk[r_, z_, n1_, n2_] := 
  FullSimplify[
   Psi[r, z, n2]*
    Laplacian[Psi[r, z, n1], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"]];

ss = Integrate[
  Kk[r, z, l1, l2] r, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {a[l1] > 0, b[l1] > 0, a[l2] > 0, b[l2] > 0}];
Kx = -1/2 2 Pi Sum[c[l1] c[l2] ss, {l1, nmax}, {l2, nmax}]


(*potential energy*)
VP1[r_, z_] := -1/Sqrt[r^2 + z^2] + 25/8 r^2 - 5/2;

Px = Integrate[
  Psi[r, z, l2]*VP1[r, z]*Psi[r, z, l1]*r , {r, 
   0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {a[l1] > 0, b[l1] > 0, a[l2] > 0, b[l2] > 0}];

Px = 2 Pi Sum[c[l1] c[l2] Px, {l1, nmax}, {l2, nmax}];



int = Integrate[
  Psi[r, z, l1] Psi[r, z, l2] r , {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {a[l1] > 0, b[l1] > 0, a[l2] > 0, b[l2] > 0}];
norm = {2 Pi Sum[c[l1] c[l2] int, {l1, nmax}, {l2, nmax}] == 
   1}; cons = 
 Join[Table[a[n] == a0j[[n]], {n, nmax}], 
  Table[b[n] == b0j[[n]], {n, nmax}], norm];


sol = NMinimize[{Kx + Px, cons}, var, 
   Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"];
```

The ground state energy is `sol[[1]]= -1.3803982710899914`, the ground state wave function $\Psi_0=\sum_j c_j\Psi(r,z,j)$ is given by

```
\[Psi]0 = Sum[c[j] Psi[r, z, j], {j, 1, nmax}] /. sol[[2]];

Plot3D[\[Psi]0, {r, 0, 2}, {z, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> "ArmyColors", MeshStyle -> White, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic] // Quiet
```

[image: Figure 1]

Second step, to compute first exited state we use

```
Do[c0[j] = c[j] /. sol[[2]];, {j, 1, nmax}]; ps10 = 
 Integrate[
  Psi[r, z, l2] Psi[r, z, l1]*r , {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {a[l1] > 0, b[l1] > 0, a[l2] > 0, b[l2] > 0}];

pen = (Sum[c0[l1] c[l2] ps10, {l1, nmax}, {l2, nmax}])^2;

cons1 = Join[Table[a[n] == a0j[[n]], {n, nmax}], 
  Table[b[n] == b0j[[n]], {n, nmax}], norm, {pen == 0}]; sol1 = 
 NMinimize[{Kx + Px, cons1}, var, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

The first exited state energy is `sol1[[1]]=-0.1936924825598707`, the first exited state wave function $\Psi_1=\sum_j c_j\Psi(r,z,j)$ is given by

```
\[Psi]1 = Sum[c[j] Psi[r, z, j], {j, 1, nmax}] /. sol1[[2]];
```

Visualization

```
Plot3D[\[Psi]1, {r, 0, 3}, {z, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> "ArmyColors", MeshStyle -> White, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic] // Quiet
```

[image: Figure 2]

**Update 1.**  To compute ground and exited states we use model described in the paper [Accurate and balanced anisotropic Gaussian type orbital
basis sets for atoms in strong magnetic fields](https://watermark.silverchair.com/244108_1_online.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAABRIwggUOBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggT_MIIE-wIBADCCBPQGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMcYSvW4WSRSneofiLAgEQgIIExckIJghAGlr3-gscrPCW8jzY3OPS-ylKfM-Rb_TFpSHYY14PjIdxGY9Lw2RPrMCAzxgvb_aqb-RrX_3j_r__qYEEBaj4YXQU5IDMOTR4Kwy1nQIQd3MvNL8J5qfnydpkTrqoJhlLHPL7QRhgf99hx_hK69qyETvviZRW0jWVehLmpZdVDqXX_aUJfH8cLCS6J-lDkC15PSTaqTW8BLa7ckXKpivTxCHj-Y3DueSlxFAsQxURAcHHaOxVEoxC4PZ_qoPuaNx2aW1qqK1YaHNYUR7BWAf3TbQNxqgzkQ-RCZOTZiP9A1X6VViXDVkqn4aIsXih7tFbCy3zfkHLIf3bLZdo1D0B9yqoOPcEmcLRdfpxb05EpGhgGdOkPyIut2u8ocwqWe8bXOi3YlvCxoG2ph1lkn6mIkgPt8q8CN-agXkJQt9VU4r3GLlnREwdNzVc7Uyrmcy3eIC-ld3HaRQuFoxNTsovScMajKRpM_1RQ7_sxjHSxGSpJI059GNRVSndwxMovVWZm3BQjx-U_LeF32F612yNageGcMaQrQ-nEdBo5CDMzrQC97CVlWJYbPylCEzGV93SR94Zjn2wm0CxTrkvv1T86DI-cQb723jdCqw0wISur-U62J6O4OfBZzjnI8dePYA3gGmt4KE6C-2MBcxi8t2lVVELRJKsduU_TJr8a85sICOao1tmbtzSW1YTx2TkI96iw-JhLYfCvO7Db1zrtY1WpjDe8vswt3IFyCMQu4RCPzly6G4Yv-JMvqNQbHjTBMRdEiQSKAhZGRIpCiz0M9Llbs6V0D7522PLudpjf9KmEo3Npsx8VZkFeiFgvREpoCrFC-7wFq-9gtNkoQBU_T7plphqBxmN3kDDQo286LjTFviTYgi9SxHHsbsxv1oyEEF8julZoPTK8nB9IA_UufZQmLCHWbgA2lBqPOaNMIMyY8sO3SHfVwATM8ul4lrWMBDzavCRD3HPzwA8MBJ8K55r6oAJID731Ip_Dv1ufmW9PPh1CRvIq7WYXNUi4-9XC6i29GPQ1PCdk8yizfQhR4d-GhGJOzRpa7NaKXEevKiHZXWh3uTZE_69FQm-t9198TUh69ofjshJj9vGc2XoAo28hFbdDkgz3YX_WqppfTa5Y8RLw9h6LhcFGGefIlCEF3MauBJcKdlLfBpdsmmRI5Pl7aWOo1jyBgZuLvFTF-dR2wEgBC0q9TXSoh6e3rpC_kge8UV-gyaSClmZnf99dssvPD18ueQFuEEDFsrsGHyb6DCbZDUlSdvxkbRkDnY9fTc0F8orweawLlN-yCNtWNUm6DHJr2r0d0DTrGerzmyweXoEswj3plNp7QZQstE0Dcwmw2ME5fEk6IfBfkyqQRqGVTnRzcshoQiikXLOYt6bp5Y-lQwMMpTmigcg1ZfG1lZ-LavONpXvS8L6h5UMX8DBO4xUiN3RRbnw73pDLmoWuQj4qWCltQ5bzfTmeGtISOBNC-f9P65hBOsWApJvXrnQngueoHt3crl0GqRwP_LEkl1U71LwTi7gkAxki0fKqUYtqWKvXTstU34GJMkONmDy1D-gtPsRxJagatT7EaSJklXDrYaSbjRYTHgpEkE0YzKaiJlTQyPD2SsHR2I_PJEOiw). They propose basis functions in the form  $\psi_j=\rho^{n_{\rho j}}z^{n_{zj}}e^{-a_j\rho^2-b_j z^2 +i m_j \phi }$ where parameters $a_j, b_j, n_{\rho j}, n_{zj}$ can be calculated with C utility available to download from [here](http://www.qtp.ufl.edu/ofdft).
Example of usage for hydrogen atoms in magnetic field B = 1.0 a.u. with electron on $s$ or $p_0$ orbitals. The ground state computation not so differ from above

```
base = {{0, 0, 0.251400, 0.026284}, {0, 0, 0.258885, 0.057253}, {0, 
    0, 0.257760, 0.086129}, {0, 0, 0.261516, 0.127117}, {0, 0, 
    0.291075, 0.187611}, {0, 0, 0.387437, 0.313972}, {0, 0, 0.720180, 
    0.676716}, {0, 0, 1.499564, 1.474065}, {0, 0, 3.225863, 
    3.210904}, {0, 0, 7.002972, 6.994196}, {0, 0, 15.240353, 
    15.235205}, {0, 0, 33.189319, 33.186299}, {0, 0, 72.290292, 
    72.288520}, {0, 0, 157.464519, 157.463480}, {0, 0, 342.997640, 
    342.997030}, {0, 0, 747.138440, 747.138082}, {0, 0, 1627.464197, 
    1627.463987}};
a0j = base[[All, 3]]; b0j = base[[All, 4]];

VP1[r_, z_] := -1/Sqrt[r^2 + z^2] + 1/8 r^2 - 1/2;

nmax = Length[a0j]; var = 
 Join[Table[a[n], {n, nmax}], Table[b[n], {n, nmax}], 
  Table[c[n], {n, nmax}]];
Psi[r_, z_, j_] := Exp[-b[j]*z^2]*Exp[-a[j]*r^2];



(*kinetic energy*)
Kk[r_, z_, n1_, n2_] := 
  FullSimplify[
   Psi[r, z, n2]*
    Laplacian[Psi[r, z, n1], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"]];

ss = Integrate[
   Kk[r, z, l1, l2] r, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {a[l1] > 0, b[l1] > 0, a[l2] > 0, b[l2] > 0}];
Kx = -1/2 2 Pi Sum[c[l1] c[l2] ss, {l1, nmax}, {l2, nmax}];


(*potential energy*)
Px = Integrate[
   Psi[r, z, l2]*VP1[r, z]*Psi[r, z, l1]*r, {r, 
    0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {a[l1] > 0, b[l1] > 0, a[l2] > 0, b[l2] > 0}];

Px = 2 Pi Sum[c[l1] c[l2] Px, {l1, nmax}, {l2, nmax}];



int = Integrate[
   Psi[r, z, l1] Psi[r, z, l2] r, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, 
    Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {a[l1] > 0, b[l1] > 0, a[l2] > 0, b[l2] > 0}];
norm = {2 Pi Sum[c[l1] c[l2] int, {l1, nmax}, {l2, nmax}] == 
   1}; cons = 
 Join[Table[a[n] == a0j[[n]], {n, nmax}], 
  Table[b[n] == b0j[[n]], {n, nmax}], norm];


sol = NMinimize[{Kx + Px, cons}, var, 
   Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"];
```

The ground state energy is `sol[[1]]=-0.8311682094831563`, while form the paper linked we have -0.83116821. To compute energy of `p0` state we have to join two basis and put $n_{zj}=1$ for this case:

```
base0 = {{0, 0, 0.251400, 0.026284}, {0, 0, 0.258885, 0.057253}, {0, 
    0, 0.257760, 0.086129}, {0, 0, 0.261516, 0.127117}, {0, 0, 
    0.291075, 0.187611}, {0, 0, 0.387437, 0.313972}, {0, 0, 0.720180, 
    0.676716}, {0, 0, 1.499564, 1.474065}, {0, 0, 3.225863, 
    3.210904}, {0, 0, 7.002972, 6.994196}, {0, 0, 15.240353, 
    15.235205}, {0, 0, 33.189319, 33.186299}, {0, 0, 72.290292, 
    72.288520}, {0, 0, 157.464519, 157.463480}, {0, 0, 342.997640, 
    342.997030}, {0, 0, 747.138440, 747.138082}, {0, 0, 1627.464197, 
    1627.463987}};

(*H2p0_B1.bas,energy=-0.2600041,-0.26000662*)
base1 = {{0, 1, 0.250013, 0.012066}, {0, 1, 0.250572, 0.026284}, {0, 
    1, 0.253650, 0.057253}, {0, 1, 0.257357, 0.090961}, {0, 1, 
    0.281270, 0.144874}, {0, 1, 0.373903, 0.267507}, {0, 1, 0.679589, 
    0.582700}, {0, 1, 1.366163, 1.269275}, {0, 1, 2.861704, 
    2.764815}, {0, 1, 6.119386, 6.022497}, {0, 1, 13.215477, 
    13.118589}, {0, 1, 28.672638, 28.575749}};


base = Join[base0, base1]; a0j = base[[All, 3]]; b0j = base[[All, 4]];

VP1[r_, z_] := -1/Sqrt[r^2 + z^2] + 1/8 r^2 - 1/2;

nmax = Length[a0j]; var = 
 Join[Table[a[n], {n, nmax}], Table[b[n], {n, nmax}], 
  Table[c[n], {n, nmax}]];
Psi[r_, z_, j_] := z Exp[-b[j]*z^2]*Exp[-a[j]*r^2];
(*kinetic energy*)
Kk[r_, z_, n1_, n2_] := 
  FullSimplify[
   Psi[r, z, n2]*
    Laplacian[Psi[r, z, n1], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"]];

ss = Integrate[
   Kk[r, z, l1, l2] r, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {a[l1] > 0, b[l1] > 0, a[l2] > 0, b[l2] > 0}];
Kx = -1/2 2 Pi Sum[c[l1] c[l2] ss, {l1, nmax}, {l2, nmax}];
(*potential energy*)
Px = Integrate[
   Psi[r, z, l2]*VP1[r, z]*Psi[r, z, l1]*r, {r, 
    0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {a[l1] > 0, b[l1] > 0, a[l2] > 0, b[l2] > 0}];

Px = 2 Pi Sum[c[l1] c[l2] Px, {l1, nmax}, {l2, nmax}];



int = Integrate[
   Psi[r, z, l1] Psi[r, z, l2] r, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, 
    Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {a[l1] > 0, b[l1] > 0, a[l2] > 0, b[l2] > 0}];
norm = {2 Pi Sum[c[l1] c[l2] int, {l1, nmax}, {l2, nmax}] == 
   1}; cons = 
 Join[Table[a[n] == a0j[[n]], {n, nmax}], 
  Table[b[n] == b0j[[n]], {n, nmax}], norm];


sol = NMinimize[{Kx + Px, cons}, var, 
   Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"];
```

The energy of `p0` state is `sol[[1]]=-0.26000636548224826` that is in a good agreement with `energy=-0.2600041` from the paper.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! This is a great answer, It is very helpful

Comment: Now I'm trying to get the second excited state by analogy and I get a very interesting situation. Due to the fact that not only the second excited state is orthogonal to the first, but also the ground state is orthogonal to the first excited state, it turns out that the minimization returns to the ground state again (because it is below the second excited level and is also orthogonal to the first excited level). In order to avoid this, it is necessary to write an additional condition into cons2?

Comment: There is a typo in the answer, a line ```Kx = -1/2 2 Pi Sum[c[l1] c[l2] ss, {l1, nmax}, {l2, nmax}];``` from the previous answer (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284809/why-does-the-minimum-eigenvalue-change-dramatically-when-one-basis-function-is-a) is missing here.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Try $\langle\Psi_2|\Psi_0\rangle=0$ and $\langle\Psi_2|\Psi_1\rangle=0$ for the second state.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment!

Comment: @MamMam See usage of C code for computation basis functions for `s` and `p0` orbitals at `B=1`.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Alex Trounev answer. Let's find the energy of the second excited state. Now it is necessary to take into account two conditions of orthogonality, since the second excited state is orthogonal to the ground state $<\Psi_2|\Psi_0>=0$, as well as to the first excited state $<\Psi_2|\Psi_1>=0$.

```
Do[c1[j] = c[j] /. sol1[[2]];, {j, 1, nmax}];
ps21 = Integrate[
   Psi[r, z, l2] Psi[r, z, l1]*r, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, 
    Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {a[l1] > 0, b[l1] > 0, a[l2] > 0, b[l2] > 0}];
pen2 = (Sum[c1[l1] c[l2] ps21, {l1, nmax}, {l2, nmax}])^2;
cons2 = Join[Table[a[n] == a0j[[n]], {n, nmax}], 
   Table[b[n] == b0j[[n]], {n, nmax}], norm, {pen == 0}, {pen2 == 0}];
sol2 = NMinimize[{Kx + Px, cons2}, var, 
  Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
sol2[[1]]

Out[110]= {-0.0640854 + 0. I, {a[1] -> 1.25, a[2] -> 1.25003, 
  a[3] -> 1.25006, a[4] -> 1.25139, a[5] -> 1.25273, a[6] -> 1.2588, 
  a[7] -> 1.26487, a[8] -> 1.2605, a[9] -> 1.30319, a[10] -> 1.54623, 
  a[11] -> 2.33719, a[12] -> 4.50731, a[13] -> 9.4263, a[14] -> 20.27,
   a[15] -> 43.977, a[16] -> 95.6752, a[17] -> 208.326, 
  a[18] -> 453.737, a[19] -> 988.322, a[20] -> 2152.8, 
  a[21] -> 4689.36, a[22] -> 10214.6, b[1] -> 0.026284, 
  b[2] -> 0.0417685, b[3] -> 0.057253, b[4] -> 0.090983, 
  b[5] -> 0.124713, b[6] -> 0.198186, b[7] -> 0.271658, 
  b[8] -> 0.417292, b[9] -> 0.61588, b[10] -> 1.00893, 
  b[11] -> 1.94988, b[12] -> 4.24735, b[13] -> 9.25185, 
  b[14] -> 20.153, b[15] -> 43.8985, b[16] -> 95.6225, 
  b[17] -> 208.291, b[18] -> 453.713, b[19] -> 988.306, 
  b[20] -> 2152.79, b[21] -> 4689.35, b[22] -> 10214.6, 
  c[1] -> -10.0667, c[2] -> 43.2035, c[3] -> -59.4205, 
  c[4] -> 58.3119, c[5] -> -44.6414, c[6] -> 22.3368, 
  c[7] -> -12.8573, c[8] -> 5.01677, c[9] -> -2.6131, 
  c[10] -> 0.860936, c[11] -> -0.291487, c[12] -> 0.0832379, 
  c[13] -> -0.0671967, c[14] -> 0.0298749, c[15] -> -0.0317333, 
  c[16] -> 0.0168776, c[17] -> -0.0175496, c[18] -> 0.0100948, 
  c[19] -> -0.00949738, c[20] -> 0.00499179, c[21] -> -0.00346965, 
  c[22] -> 0.000418}}

Out[111]= -0.0640854 + 0. I
```

The value of the received energy ($E_2=-0.0640854$) is higher than the value from the literature ($E_2=-0,07365$).

Is this due to the fact that the considered number of basis functions (22) is not enough to describe the higher excited states?

Such a difference in energies is due to the mixing of levels. If only the third excited state is taken into account in mixing, then the expression for the second excited state will take the form: $|\Psi_2>=A_1|\Psi_{2, pure}>+A_2|\Psi_{3, pure}>$

$|\Psi_2>=A_1(c[1]_{2,\Psi_{pure}}|\Psi(\alpha_1,\beta_1)>+...)$+
$A_2(c[1]_{3,\Psi_{pure}}|\Psi(\alpha_1,\beta_1)>+...)$

Comment: @Alex Trounev, I have created an additional answer that calculates the second excited state, can you please see if it is calculated correctly. The energy of the second excited state (-0.0640854) turned out to be higher than expected (-0,07365). Do I understand correctly that this is due to the fact that the problem has a fixed number of basis functions? In order to get the correct energy value, it is necessary to increase the number of basis functions?

Comment: It depends on method, but using orthogonalization and normalization only we can compute mixture of states as well.  Let try `FindMinimum` with `c2` computed above as starting point.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, thanks! I tried to use ```FindMinimum```, but the result did not change. That is, I just changed one line in the code ```sol2 = FindMinimum[{Kx + Px, cons2}, var]``` and the result (-0.0640857) is the same as when using NMinimize.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, could you please write in more detail about mixing states, this part is not very clear yet.

Comment: In this case mixing states is $\psi=\sum_{i=2}^{nmax}C_i \psi_i$, where $\psi_i$ is orthogonal to $\psi_0, \psi_1$. It is why we need some additional  constraint to select exited states $\psi_i$.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, thanks! I've updated my answer, please take a look. Did I understand correctly that now the second excited state is some combination of a pure second excited state (without admixtures of other states) plus, in the first order, an admixture from the third excited level, in the second order, an admixture from the fourth excited state, etc.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, And another question, in this approach we have a fixed number of basis functions (in this case, 22). But the basis set in the general case can be any, that is, if this basis set is expanded, then when adding each new basis function (22+1), three additional parameters will appear (с[23], a[23], b[23])?

Comment: Please, pay attention, that in a case of matrix method we need about 200 basis functions to compute  first 10 eigenvalues with high accuracy - see my answer on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200448/eigenvalue-problem . In this regards the optimization method working very good on 22 basis functions.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, thanks for the useful link! I would like to clarify, so now the only way to get finer values for the excited states is to increase the number of basis functions?

Comment: Actually, as I understand from the paper 'Accurate and balanced anisotropic Gaussian type orbital basis sets for atoms in strong magnetic fields' we need to use new basis functions for every orbitals. Therefore, our approach is good, but to compute $\Psi_2$ we need new basis.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, thanks! Yes, I realize. Is it possible to achieve more accurate energy values with the help of minimization, adding one basis function and, accordingly, increasing the number of parameters by three (с[22+i], a[22+i], b[22+i]) each time? I mean the first step is plus one additional basic function (three new parameters с[23], a[23], b[23]), the second step is the next additional basic function (three new parameters с[24], a[24], b[24]), and so on.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, I read the article and it is not clear how the authors optimized the basis, only the optimization results are described in detail, but the optimization process itself is not very detailed, so it is not entirely clear how to get parameter sets by analogy with how the authors of the article did it.

Comment: This is very long time research starting from C. Aldrich and R. L. Greene, Phys. Status Solidi B 93, 343 (1979). On every step somebody added new correlation. Finally we have very complicated empirical model.  There is C code to compute $a_j, b_j, n_{\rho j}, n_{zj}$ for base functions   $\psi_j=\rho^{n_{\rho j}}z^{n_{zj}}e^{-a_j\rho^2-b_j z^2 +i m_j \phi }$. While we try to compute exited states using one base for ground state. :)

Comment: @Alex Trounev, yes, I agree, I have read the C. Aldrich and R. L. Greene article too but in reality it is also not clear how they find the parameters $a_j$ and $b_j$ for the basis. What the authors write about it: "For given quantum numbers m and q , the parameters $a_1, a_N, β_1, β_M$ and were varied in a four dimensional optimization search which minimized the sum of the eigen- values of interest." From one sentence it is completely unclear how to do this and there isn't more information about it in the article.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, as for the C code, I took the parameters from this code. I was able to run the code and get the parameters that I provide in the task description.

Comment: Yes, but please pay attention that $\psi_j$ for exited states is more complicated then you used. See Update 1 to my answer.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, thanks! Yes, you are right, for higher levels, a more complex wave function should be used (for instance like in your example for 2p_0 level) But my task question about excited states of s level that is 2s, 3s, 4s ... For all these states the usual Gaussian function should be used. There aren't energy of 2s, 3s, 4s ... states in table 1 of the article. But 2s there is here in table 1: https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.54.287 and other excited states here in table 1: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/pssb.2220930140

Comment: @Alex Trounev, I would like to draw attention to the fact that to get the energy from the Aldrich, C., & Greene, R. L article it's needed the value from the table 1 to subtract the field value and divide by 2. For example for 3s state: value from the table 1 for B=5 is equal 4.8527 so the energy of the 3s state = (4.8527-5)/2 = -0,07365

Comment: They used matrix 150x150, that what I pointed out about matrix method.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, yes, they used a large matrices. Could you please explain me, how did they find the coefficients $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ for such a large basis set? If it's not difficult, then please demonstrate it

Comment: We have very long discussion here. I can recommend you upvote my answer here and previous as well, and start a new one topic about 150x150 matrix. :)

Comment: @Alex Trounev, yes, of course, thanks!